# Generating Symbols in release binaries with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, symbols

Update: I posted a comment on [John Robbins](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/default.aspx) blog about the. He wrote a response here:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/06/19/do-pdb-files-affect-performance.aspx

The project I am working on does not build symbols for its release binaries, and I would like to change this.

Some info:

- Mostly C++ code base, some C#.
- Compiled under VS2k5, will be moving to VS2k8 Team System.
- Time critical software.
- Must have optimizations enabled.
- Source code is provided to customer so full symbols are fine.

What are the best command line switches to generate what I need, and what, if any, performance hits am I going to take?

Also, are there any "Gotchas" to be aware of?

Comment: The linked blog no longer exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: I posted a comment on [John Robbins](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/default.aspx) blog about the. He wrote a response here:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/06/19/do-pdb-files-affect-performance.aspx

I found the following link on microsofts website:
[Generating and Deploying Debug Symbols with Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260783(VS.60).aspx)

This link pertains to Visual C++ 6, but I am assuming these instructions are the same for Visual C++ 8(2005) and 9(2008).

The information it gives is very similar to the link provided by TheBlack but more in-depth.

Answer (score 6):

Generating debug symbols (ie PDB files) is just creating an external file that a debugger can reference when looking at your code in memory.  It doesn't affect the code that the compiler or linker generate (sort of like generating a .MAP file).

Now if you're talking about defining _DEBUG in a release build, that's a whole different question.

Answer (score 3):

The [/Zi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019) switch in Visual C++ will create a PDB, but this setting also implies additional settings that will make the DLL or EXE larger.  Specifically, `/Zi` implies [/DEBUG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=vs-2019), which implies [/INCREMENTAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=vs-2019), [/OPT:NOREF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=vs-2019) and [/OPT:NOICF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=vs-2019).  The last three make the compiled DLL or EXE bigger, but they can be overridden by specifying `/OPT:REF` and `/OPT:ICF` in addition to `/Zi`.  There is no need to override `/INCREMENTAL`, as `/OPT:REF` and/or `/OPT:ICF` will ensure a full, non-incremental link.

Source: [Correctly Creating Native C++ Release Build PDBs](https://www.wintellect.com/correctly-creating-native-c-release-build-pdbs/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the command line, but you need to set debug symbols both in c++ compiler config (program database) and the linker (generate debug info) in the IDE.

If you find the settings in the project, you can use help to see which command-lines they refer to.